# How do you get screenshots for devices you don't have?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I've created a third party keyboard for iOS, and am trying to submit it to the App Store. My screenshot that I would like to use, is sombody using my keyboard mid-conversation. Naturaly, this was easy to do from my iPhone. But infortunaly, i'm not sure how to go about doing that on the iOS simulators for other devices. There's no way to send them a text, therefore I'm not sure what to do. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have to use the messages app to demonstrate your keyboard? Can you use another app that is available on the emulator?

Comment: Theoretically I could, but I'd rather use the same screenshot I have.

Comment: Without have the actual device, you're going to have to create something in Photoshop because the emulator doesn't have a Messages app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to use & upload original screenshots but to take the screenshots from your phone and implement them into a created image including text, etc. which you'd upload as screenshot to iTunesConnect. You then would only need one actual screenshot size and it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Set up Apple's [TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) group and invite people who do have required devices. That's kind of extra trouble, but as an additional benefit you'd get real people testing your app before release.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from the simulator since there is no messages app. Maybe you can do some magic with Photoshop

Comment: Is that really my only route? That kinda sucks.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way. Why don't you just use the screenshots from your phone? is it really necessary to use screenshots from other devices?

Comment: I believe I need to do one for each iPhone size, no?

Comment: Mmmm right... I forgot about that... Then I don't think you have another option

Comment: Hi @DevonCarlson clearly getting other devices to work for you through FlightTest, or just getting a screenshot from the messages app from friends for each device kind, would work for you. Since the custom keyboard takes the same size as the OS keyboard, you will be able to mix screenshots. There is no shorter workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you can use [JSQMessagesViewController](http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/). It's not 100% the same, but it does look very similar.